# SMS app doesn't come to foreground when started

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using the code below:

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/" + unObjObj.getThreadId()));

smsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);   

mContext.startActivity(smsIntent);
```

To launch the SMS app, with the right thread open.

It works fine if the SMS app is not already running in which case, it gets launched and the right sms thread is opened.

The problem comes with the SMS app is in background (seen in recents), in which case it is not brought to the foreground.

I've even tried passing the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` flag but nothing changed.

What am I missing?

Comment: what happens if you remove `smsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`?